# No value given for required parameters

Tags: c#, parameters, oledb, updating, aceoledb

I am trying to make a button that updates account nickname using the account number but Im getting an error.

[image]

```
  private void change_nickname_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = "update customers set [CustomerCode]='" + customercode.Text + "',[CustomerName]='" + customername.Text + "',[Address]='" + customeraddress.Text + "',[PhoneNumber]='" + customerphone.Text + "',[Account]='" + Account + "',[AccountNickname]='" + accountnickname.Text + "',[Overdraft]='" + overdraft.Text + "' where AccountNumber=" + accountnumber.Text + "";
            MessageBox.Show(query);
            command.CommandText = query;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data updated successfuly!");
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/End36.png

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Oh its an access database. OleDb.

Comment: you should use Parameterized query's doing it dynamically you will get yourself all mixed up trying to match `'` and double `" "` quotes I would suggest wrapping your code around `using statment` as well

Comment: One or more of the parameters to your update statement is null (or empty) while the database is expecting a value. Check the values of your text fields. Also you just have `Account` and not `account.Text` for your `Account` field. Is this deliberate?

Comment: Yes it it because Account is a variable that i can later use for something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah the problem was solved guys thank for all the help. The problem was here.

```
where AccountNumber=" + accountnumber.Text + "";
        MessageBox.Show(query);
```

I changed this to

```
where AccountNumber='" + accountnumber.Text + "'";
        MessageBox.Show(query);
```

And it worked somehow.